# how to get properly grok pattern for line without spaces

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

how to get properly grok pattern for log format like this:

i tried use %{NOTSPACE} but it takes whole line.

```
<firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Adams</lastname><issuedBy>USA</issuedBy>
```

JSON must be like this.

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Adams",
  "issuedBy": "USA",
}
```

Comment: If you are using logstash then I would suggest you to use [xml filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html) instead of creating a complex grok pattern.

Comment: seems xml plugin not will work because xml format are taken from "*.log" files not xml.

Comment: also this file log logging java traces...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next Grok Pattern:

```
<firstname>%{WORD:firstname}</firstname><lastname>%{WORD:lastname}</lastname><issuedBy>%{WORD:issuedBy}</issuedBy>
```

Output example with the line you used in your question:

```
  "firstname": "John",
  "issuedBy": "USA",
  "lastname": "Adams"
```

If you want something more complex but reliable, you can always use XML filter plugin as mentioned earlier in this question.

Keep on mind that using above Grok Filter will be only useful when data is always formatted as the line you posted.